# php math function results wrong output

Tags: php, session, math

I grabbed value of silver from yahoo finance and added 0.10 to the current value.. it is showing right result..

```
$yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?";

$params = array(
    'q'      => 'select * from html where url=@url and xpath=@xpath;',
    'url'    => 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=XAGUSD%3DX&ql=1',
    'xpath'  => '//*[@id="yfs_g00_xagusd=x"]',
    'env'    => 'http://datatables.org/alltables.env',
    'format' => 'json',
);

$yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . http_build_query($params);

$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json   = curl_exec($session);
$phpObj = json_decode($json);

if ($phpObj->query->count > 0) {
    $price = $phpObj->query->results->span->content;
}
?>
<div>  <?php echo $price; ?> which is current value </div>
<div><?php echo $price + .10; ?> where 0.10 is added</div>
```

**[click to Run the code here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gyayWd)**

But when i try that for gold price , the result shows wrong output ie 1 or 2

```
$yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?";

$params = array(
    'q'      => 'select * from html where url=@url and xpath=@xpath;',
    'url'    => 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=XAUUSD%3DX&ql=1',
    'xpath'  => '//*[@id="yfs_g00_xauusd=x"]',
    'env'    => 'http://datatables.org/alltables.env',
    'format' => 'json',
);

$yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . http_build_query($params);

$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json   = curl_exec($session);
$phpObj = json_decode($json);

if ($phpObj->query->count > 0) {
    $price = $phpObj->query->results->span->content;
}
?>
<div> <?php echo $price; ?> which is current value</div>
<div> <?php echo $price + .10; ?> where 0.10 is added</div>
```

**[Click to run the code here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6XyP65)**

Can anyone please help me in this matter.. any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for silver is `28.7100` -- which can be transformed to a floating number -- which is why adding `0.10` to it works.

On the other hand, the value you get for gold is `1,597.2800` -- which cannot be converted to a number **(note the `','`)** -- which is why adding `0.10` to it doesn't work.

You have to transform that string to one that can be converted to a float, by removing that `','` ; this can be done with [`str_replace()`][1] :

```
$str = '1,597.2800';
$str = str_replace(',', '', $str);
```

And, then, adding `0.10` to it becomes possible :

```
var_dump($str + 0.10);
```

Will give :

```
float 1597.38
```

After that, you can of course re-format the new calculated-value.

You'll typically want to use the [**`number_format()`**][2] function, in order to do that.

For example, you could use something like this:

```
$str = '1,597.2800';
$str = str_replace(',', '', $str);
$price = $str + 0.10;
echo number_format($price, 2);
```

And you'd get the following output:

```
1,597.38
```

Comment: ok i did ka try and it really worked out.. but i need to show the price in comma seperated .. ie 1597.28 is the output made with str_replace(); but i need to show 1,597.28 in div(i again need to add comma in the result which is to be displayed)..can you please suggest

Comment: @coolnicq you'll probably want to use the `number_format()` function -- I've edited my answer to include an example, but feel free to take a look at it's manual page to see what parameters it accepts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to execute PHP code now, but I think it is an issue with your number format.

The number is `1,597.2800`. The comma `,` is not a valid character, so 1,597.2800 is being converted to 1. Then if you had 0.1 it gives 1.1 as a result.

As your number is first treated as a string, you should remove the comma before you do any operation. A simple `str_replace(',', '', $price);` should work.

Comment: Yes, it's just a problem with PHP converting a string to an integer. You can also convert it to a float `$number = (float) str_replace(',', '', $price);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the comma in `1,597`. PHP will not take that string as a number. It stops at the comma.

Remove the comma and convert the string to a number.

`<?php echo floatval(str_replace(',','',$price)) + .10; ?>`

You can leave off the explicit number conversion if you like because `+` forces implicit conversion:

`<?php echo str_replace(',','',$price) + .10; ?>`

Use `number_format()` to put the commas back. The `,2` specifies the number of decimal places: you may want 4.

`<?php echo number_format(floatval(str_replace(',','',$price)) + .10,2); ?>`